# How to use CloudFormer to generate a template?

Tags: templates, aws-cloudformation

New to AWS and trying to understand CloudFormation templates. I created two EC2 micro Windows instances instances. I go to CloudFormer and it wants a template file or it offers a default template URL.

I'm under the impression that it should read the resources I've created and auto-generate the template.

If it wants a URL for the instances I dont know how to get them. And I'm trying to generate a template so I don't have one to feed to it as I'm trying to get one generated from what resources I have created on AWS.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormer is an AMI instance that you run, if the screen you are looking at is asking for a URL then you might be into CloudFormation..

There is a link here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1048 explaining how to launch CloudFormer.

You can launch it directly here:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#cstack=sn~AWSCloudFormer|turl~https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/AWSCloudFormer.template

You might just need to change the region you want to run CloudFormer in.

Answer (score 0):

Using ami you can create an ec2 and access it's url to access cloudformer console as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html). But bear in mind CloudFormer creates templates where all the resources are stacked under resource section and other sections are empty since it can't intelligently decide what parameters or conditions you could have chosen for your existing resources. After the template is created it required manually mending it to make it reusable by filling in other sections.